# Find substring in string when beginning with some string to space (whole word)

Tags: php, space, substr, strpos

I'm trying to find substring from string and get that part from it that begins width word - $search. Now, it's working but I want to find this substring to whole word, to space. How to do that?

I'm using:

```html
  $results[] = [ 'value' => substr(strip_tags($query->content), strpos(strip_tags($query->content),$search) ,30)];
```

I also tried with:

```html
 $results[] = [  'value' => substr(strip_tags($query->content), strpos(strip_tags($query->content),$search) ,strpos(strip_tags($query->content), ' ',30))];
```

But it finds substring not to interval.

Edited: I did it, but all records repeat two times. I have to show title and content only twice. I had to make loop for $matches  but now, recoreds repeat. How to fix that? Thanks.

```html
foreach ($sql as $query) {


preg_match('#(' . preg_quote($search, '#') . '.{30,}?)\s#', strip_tags($query->content), $matches);

foreach($matches as $key=>$val) {
$results[] = [  'id' => $query->title, 'value' => $val];
}

}

return $results;
```

Comment: Your username quite rightly fits so; sorry for the sarcasm. It's really unclear as to what you mean here? Can you give a small example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be done with regex

```
preg_match('#(' . preg_quote($search, '#') . '.{30,}?)\s#', strip_tags($query->content), $match);
$results[] = [ 'value' => $match[1] ];
```

Comment: I'm searching in ```strip_tags($query->content),``` for occurance of $search and when I find it, I want to show 30 characters beginning width $search but to show these characters to white space, not to cut word.

Comment: so you want to show a minimum of 30 characters and than cut on the next following whitespace?

Comment: Yes, but this substring to start with the word that user is searching - $search.

Comment: so this woul be (' . preg_quote($search, '#') . '.{30,}?)\s this will start at $search an take a minumum of 30 characters + the rest until the first whitespace appers, but this will not work when there a no 30 characters or no whitespace after the minimum of 30, for example this text "hello i am living in a small town in germany in central europe" (living.{30,}?)\s will match "living in a small town in germany in" but (town.{30,}?)\s will not match

Comment: How to use this is my example? I'm using substr ans strpos

Comment: It's throwing undefined offset 1, and I think I should add substr().

Comment: this means it does not match the text, do you have an example text with an example result?

Comment: Yes, I have - a word that I'msearching from my search field. It's there.

Comment: I changed $match[1] with $match and it's fine! Thank you very much!

Comment: I edited my question, I'm trying to fix now - title and content repeat two times because of loop, how to fix it?

Comment: try to replace preg_match('#(' . preg_quote($search, '#') . '.{30,}?)\s#', strip_tags($query->content), $matches);
 with preg_match('#' . preg_quote($search, '#') . '.{30,}?\s#', strip_tags($query->content), $matches); than you shuld get just 1 match instead of 2 matches

Comment: But it's the same, what to change?

Comment: removing the opening and closing () from the regex

Comment: Thank you, I have to learn regex. And last thing, how to make this for also $search_en and $search_ru? I have to make sepatare preg_match?

Comment: what exactly do you mean with $search_en and $search_ru ?

Comment: I make search form and I'm using transliterate function - to translate what use is searching in two other languages - $search_en and $search_ru and I want to preg_match not only by $search, but also by $search_en and $search_ru.

Comment: I did it in this way: ``` $pattern_array = array($search, $search_en, $search_ru);
                        foreach($pattern_array as $pattern) {
                            preg_match('#' . preg_quote($pattern, '#') . '.{30,}?\s#', strip_tags($query->content), $matches);
                        }```